# Order statistic of dependent chi-squares

Tags: chi-squared-test, independence, order-statistics

I was wondering if someone could please help me with the following. I am trying to find the pdf of a set of dependent $\chi^2$ random variables. Suppose $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ are independent normals $x_i \sim N(\mu_i, \sigma_i^2)$, not necessarily identical. Assume $n$ and all $\mu_i$'s and $\sigma_i's$ are known parameters, so this is really a probability, not an inferential statistics question. Select all possible subsets of size $n-1, n-2,..., n-k$ with $(n-k \geq 1)$ from this set. Each subset will then have a mean and variance equal to $\sum_{j\mbox{th subset}} \mu_j$  and $\sum_{j\mbox{th subset}} \sigma_j^2$, respectively. For each subset then compute the standardized sums:

$(\sum_{j\mbox{th subset}} x_j - \sum_{j\mbox{th subset}} \mu_j)^2/\sum_{j\mbox{th subset}} \sigma_j^2$

Each sum is then a $\chi^2_1$ (one degree of freedom). Question is to find the pdf of the $l$th order statistic of such set of $\chi_1^2$'s. Clearly, the sums cannot be independent $\chi^2$'s, since the subsets share some of the original normals.

I have seen some related work on 'subset selection' problems in regression, specifically, a paper by Arvesen and McCabe of 1974. They mention their problem involves exactly this distribution, but then I believe they do not provide it, only providing asymptotic results and Monte Carlo simulations.

Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated! (I hope this edited version of the question is clearer).

Comment: Welcome to the site, Ernie. This question is interesting and has good potential! However, I find the exposition in the first paragraph, particularly the second half, a bit too imprecise to follow. Can you clarify what "standardized sum" you are referring to when you claim it has a chi squared distribution with one degree of freedom? What parameters of the normals, if any of them, do you assume are known? I look forward to an updated post. Cheers.